# cakephp paginate - sort records per categories (has different categories per record)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I'm trying to sort records per categories and each record has one or more categories if the user has categories he likes.. If none, then just display all records..
Example, if a record has Food Category and the user signed in happens to have selected Food as one of his interests then the list of records displayed will be sorted having the records under Food category on top of the list..

I have

```
$this->Steplist->virtualFields['in_like'] = "IF(Record.category_id IN ($interests), 0, 1)";
$order["in_like"] = 'asc';
```

then

```
'order' => $order
```

for **$this->Paginator->settings**

then 
int for the category_id

Now, instead of having 1 category for each record, it has to be changed to several categories. To avoid changing so much since the site is complete now, I simply change the **category_id (int)** to **categories (varchar)** with category ids separated by commas.. so instead of 5 for example, it can now be 3,5,7 if there are several categories attached to the record..

I tried to change the virtual field condition to:

```
$this->Steplist->virtualFields['in_like'] = "IF(Record.categories IN ($interests), 0, 1)";
```

but the result is not correct.
How do I do this instead (cakephp 2.4.3)?

Comment: still don't understand what are you trying to do...

Comment: I'm trying to sort the records per categories and each record has one or more categories if the user has categories he likes.. If none, then just display all records.. @IsaacRajaei

Comment: @IsaacRajaei Edited my question with an introduction of what I'm trying to do..

Comment: where do you pass the $order on you pagination

Comment: @IsaacRajaei $order is passed to 'order' like this : $this->Paginator->settings = array(
           'conditions' => array('Record.status =' => 'public'),
           'limit' => 10,
           'order' => $order
       );

Comment: I don't think using virtual field here is a good idea while there is lots of other alternatives... I suggest you to update your question with your model and controller....

Answer (score 0):

This will work on settigns pagination.

```
class RecipesController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator');        

    public function list_recipes() {   

        $paginate = array(
           'limit' => 25,
           'order' => array(
               'Post.title' => 'asc'
           )
        );

        $this->Paginator->settings = $paginate;

        // similar to findAll(), but fetches paged results
        $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Recipe');
        $this->set('data', $data);
    }
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

[Limitations of virtualFields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields)

**But in general if you are using virtual fields**: The implementation of virtualFields has a few limitations. First you cannot use virtualFields on associated models for conditions, order, or fields arrays. Doing so will generally result in an SQL error as the fields are not replaced by the ORM. This is because it difficult to estimate the depth at which an associated model might be found.

You can use asort() or sort() after retrieving your data